# Start Service from Notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

is it possible to start a service from a notification. 
The normal way of starting an activity is working perfectly, but I need some pre checks of data before actually starting the app.

I've tested it with including a valid service in the notification intent, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> It is possible to start a service from a notification.

You have to use PendingIntent.getService instead of pendingIntent.getActivity.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mContext, HandleNotificationClickService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(mContext,contentTitle , contentText, pendingIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(CALLER_ID_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: That definitely should be the accepted answer! "PendingIntent.getService instead of pendingIntent.getActivity" is the correct way of doing it!

Comment: @keide how to pause the service using pendingIntent in notification. we need call the stop method of the service class.

Comment: When I start the service like described above I get an runtime exception: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) - <VM does not provide monitor information> - ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) line: 2561 - ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) line: 141

Comment: Deprecated though. But `PendingIntent.getService` helped me anyhow +1

Comment: @devaldcool no it is not deprecated. [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int)](AndroidDocs)

Comment: How to send extra??

Answer (score 6):

Create a broadcast receiver, receive the message from notification and then start the service.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the BroadCastReceiver. Could put all checks into that so I don't need the Service anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void createNotification(String message) 

{

   Intent intent = new Intent(this, Yourservice.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
         0);

   NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icond)
         .setContentTitle("Start Launcher")
         .setContentText(message)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setOngoing(true)
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION , notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: just pass your message string in method call this createNotification("test"); and .setContentTitle("Start Launcher") is your title of notification Yourservice.class is the service name of your created service.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is working greatly..
I will write down the whole example..
you can modify the answer if you need it

**This is for Notification create**

```
public void createNotification2(String aMessage) {
    final int NOTIFY_ID = 11;
    String name = getString(R.string.app_name);
    String id = getString(R.string.app_name); // The user-visible name of the channel.
    String description = getString(R.string.app_name); // The user-visible description of the channel.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    if (notifManager == null) {
        notifManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(description);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    } else {

    }
    Intent Off_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    Off_broadcastIntent.setAction("on");
    Off_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "1");
    PendingIntent Off_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, Off_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent on_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    on_broadcastIntent.setAction("off");
    on_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "0");
    PendingIntent on_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, on_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent cancel_broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, Database_Update.class);
    cancel_broadcastIntent.setAction("cancel");
    cancel_broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "close");
    PendingIntent cancel_actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, cancel_broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent content_intent = new Intent(this, Status_Page.class);
    content_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, content_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
            .addAction(R.drawable.block, "ON", Off_actionIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.notification, "OFF", on_actionIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.clear, "CLOSE", cancel_actionIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR|Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notifManager.notify(11, notification);
}
```

**In Android Menifest**

```
<service android:name=".Database_Update"></service>
```

**This is service class**

```
public class Database_Update extends Service {
String result="";

Realm realm;
BlockList blockList;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("notification.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("SERVICE","SERVICE CHECKING");
    result=intent.getStringExtra("toastMessage");
    Log.d("SERVICE",result);
    if (realm!=null){
        Log.d("SERVICE","realm working");
    }else {
        Log.d("SERVICE","Realm not working");
    }
    blockList=realm.where(BlockList.class).equalTo("package_name", "BLOCK_ALL").findFirst();
    try {
        Log.d("SERVICE",blockList.getStatus());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Error Line Number", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    realm.beginTransaction();
    if (result.equals("1")){
        if (blockList==null){
            BlockList blockList_new=realm.createObject(BlockList.class);
            blockList_new.setPackage_name("BLOCK_ALL");
            blockList_new.setStatus("yes");
        }else {
            blockList.setStatus("yes");
        }
        Log.d("SERVICE","BLOCKING NOTIFICATION");
        Toast.makeText(this, "BLOCKING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (result.equals("0")){
        if (blockList==null){
            BlockList blockList_new=realm.createObject(BlockList.class);
            blockList_new.setPackage_name("BLOCK_ALL");
            blockList_new.setStatus("no");
        }else {
            blockList.setStatus("no");
        }
        Log.d("SERVICE","ALLOW NOTIFICATION");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ALLOW NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (result.equals("close")){
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(11);
        Log.d("SERVICE","REMOVING");
        Toast.makeText(this, "CLOSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    realm.commitTransaction();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // We don't provide binding, so return null
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (realm!=null){
        realm.close();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "REMOVING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```